# Modern Java Concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading

Using the newer Java abstractions how would you make threads 'stoppable'?

For example, a media player is plays an MP3 file and has a pause button so using older Java you might have (roughly) a class like this:

```
 volatile boolean stopPlaying = false;

 new Thread(() - > {
    void play() {
        stopPlaying = false;
        while(songHasntEnded && !stopPlaying) {
            //decode next part of song and play
        }
    }
}).start();
```

and an action listener's stop button might have this:

```
void stop() {
        stopPlaying = true;
        //close file etc
}
```

How would this scenario (or a more general one, I'm not trying to reinvent the mp3 player) be implemented using `java.util.concurrent`?

Does it provide a way to avoid using a volatile variable to command a thread to stop?

Does it provide a way to 'pause' a thread so a new one doesn't have to be created every time I stop and play another song?

I've been using the lower level thread mechanisms and I think enough is enough so any help appreciated.

Comment: Executors are for when you have many short tasks. For a single long task, there's not really an advantage over a Thread. No, java.util.concurrent does not have a way to pause or stop tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been using the lower level thread mechanisms and I think enough is enough ...

Unfortunately, neither `java.util.concurrent` or any other part of the Java library in recent Java provides a new mechanism.

Your options are testing a shared variable (`volatile` or using `synchronized`) or using the `Thread` interrupt mechanism.

There is no safe and reliable mechanism for pausing threads.  To understand why read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend()) for the deprecated `Thread.suspend()` method.  If you think about it, there simply isn't a safe and reliable way to pause threads.  For what it is worth, I can't think of any other language that supports this kind of thing (safely) either.

For example:

- [How can I suspend and resume a thread from another thread?](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~xleroy/linuxthreads/faq.html#E) from the pthreads FAQ:

Comment: So this is more of a theoretical thing than a language barrier. Maybe this procedure could be wrapped in a class that prevents the user from "locking this monitor prior to calling resume".

Comment: @Dziugas - Think of it this way.  There have been lots of really smart people on the Sun / Oracle Java team.  There are many more really smart Java experts in academia and in industry.  None of these really smart people have (to my knowledge) proposed a safe solution this problem.  If you think you have an idea, feel free to work it up into a fully formed solution ... and let the experts review it. In the meantime, I remain skeptical.

Comment: I think your last paragraph is a bit misleading... Thread.suspend() is inherently broken, but that does not mean that there is no way to suspend a thread/ that OP needs to create a new thread every time he wants to pause his playback. The example in the question works correctly and can be extended to pause instead of stop the thread. [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) suggests a similar solution.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard - Feel free to write your own answer.  But I don't think the OP is looking for an extension of his approach.  I think he wants a different (more general / less "clunky") approach.